# How to select float values by mantissa length?

Tags: postgresql, select, precision, numerical-methods

I have a column with double precision values. I am trying to select only those with precision greater than a tenth (e.g., 24.13, 1.347, etc.).

I know I can convert the float to a string and query based on string length using the following:

```
select * from schema.table where char_length(to_char(float_column, 'FM999999999D999999999')) > 3;
```

This will return all the rows with more than 1 decimal place *if* the integer portion of the number is single digit (eg., it will return 24.1).

**How can I select any float value that has a mitissa length greater than one?**

Comment: Because of rounding issues with floating point numbers, your request is rather indeterminate.  I would suggest that you store the values using `numeric`/`decimal`.

Comment: If this was numeric/decimal you could test like: `your_column%.1<>0`? But Float won't float.

Comment: @JNevill that works if I cast as numeric. `select * from schema.table where float_column::numeric %.1 <> 0;`

Comment: it may seem to work.  but float doesn't support = or <> in any reliable way.

Comment: How do you know that `24.1` is not `24.10` ? You cannot determine the precision just by look at the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`split_part()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
with my_table(float_column) as (
values
(24.13::float), (1.347), (12345), (.1)
)

select float_column, split_part(float_column::text, '.', 2)
from my_table;

 float_column | split_part 
--------------+------------
        24.13 | 13
        1.347 | 347
        12345 | 
          0.1 | 1
(4 rows)
```

So your query may look like this:

```
select *
from my_table 
where length(split_part(float_column::text, '.', 2)) > 1;

 float_column 
--------------
        24.13
        1.347
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the value as `numeric` (fixed point versus floating point), then you could simply do:

```
where floor(col * 100) <> floor(col * 10) * 10
```

Unfortunately, there are edge cases where this logic doesn't work for floating point numbers, because you can get something like 21.99999999997.

Comment: This selects values that have _only_ tenths values (or 0), the comparison operator needs to be flipped to select the values with more than one decimal digit. Then it works if cast as numeric:   `select * from schema.table where where floor(float_column::numeric * 100) <> floor(float_column * 10) * 10;`

Comment: @DonPeat . . . I misread the question.  But the point remains:  if the number of digits of precision is important use fixed point representations.

Answer (score 0):

look for rounding errors:

```
where round(float_column,1) <> round(float_column,5)
```